# pattern singleton class Cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Написать класс-оболочку для работы с `cookie`. Класс должен содержать следующий
набор функций:

- сохранение
- удаление
- редактирование
- считывание

По умолчанию кука должна устанавливаться на 1 год. Класс должен быть реализован
таким образом, чтобы нельзя было создать более одного экземпляра класса.

```
class Cookie {

public static function instance() {
    static $instance = false;
    if( $instance === false ) {
        $instance = new static();
    }
    return $instance;
}


public static function setCookie($key, $value, $time = 31536000) {
    setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/') ;
}

public static function getCookie($key) {
    if ( isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ){
        return $_COOKIE[$key];
    }
    return null;
}

public static function updateCookie($key, $value, $time = 31536000) {
    if ( isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ){
        self::deleteCookie($key);
        setcookie($key, $value, time() + $time, '/');
    }
    return null;
}

public static function deleteCookie($key)   {
    if ( isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ){
        self::getCookie($key);
        unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
    }
}
```

}

вот что сделал я, и не могу понять, то ли я

Comment: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить.

Comment: допустим если так

Answer (score 2):

> pattern singleton

Синглтон характеризуется двумя признаками:

- Публичный статический метод для получения экземпляра класса
- Все методы, позволяющие создать копию экземпляра(в т.ч. и конструктор) - приватные

Простейший сниппет для Singleton выглядит так:

```
class A {
  private static $a;
  public static function get() {
    return static::$a?: static::$a = new static();
  }

  private function __construct(){}
  private function __clone(){}
  private function __wakeup(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Покажу на простом примере паттерна синглотона:

```
class Cookie
{
    public static function instance()
    {
      static $instance = false;
      if( $instance === false )
      {
        // Позднее статическое связывание (PHP 5.3+)
        $instance = new static();
      }

      return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Make constructor private, so nobody can call "new Class".
     */
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Make clone magic method private, so nobody can clone instance.
     */
    private function __clone() {}

    /**
     * Make sleep magic method private, so nobody can serialize instance.
     */
    private function __sleep() {}

    /**
     * Make wakeup magic method private, so nobody can unserialize instance.
     */
    private function __wakeup() {}

    //Добавляете вашу логику

}
```

И потом можете работать с этим объектом:

```
$cookie = Cookie::instance();
$cookie->setCookie('name', 'value');
$value = $cookie->getCookie('name');
...
```

Comment: поправил? так он будет выглядеть?

Comment: Должен, проверьте и тогда уже скажите работает или нет

Comment: работать то работает) спасибо, проблема в том что до конца я не понял выполняет ли "наша" :D реализация условия задания

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин да, это и есть синглтон :)